# HTTPSession created when jsp page is loaded

Tags: tomcat, httpsession

I've added a very simple JSP page in my Tomcat webapp for HTTP 500, this page is not calling any of my servlets and I'm not creating any session anywhere but I can see in my HttpSessionListener that a new session is created while calling this page....

Would you please tell me why tomcat is creating a session for each JSP page browsed in my webapp ? I initially create a new session only when user logs successfully, it may cause security issue....

Comment: The must be (by specification) an HttpSession object for every HttpRequest. So if you access a JSP page (which is actually a servlet, too, see [Life cycle of a JSP Page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial-update2/doc/JSPIntro4.html)), it creates an HttpRequest on the server side, thus an HttpSession, too.

Comment: Could you put new Exception().printStackTrace() into your HttpSessionListener?

Comment: The default behavior of the j2ee application server is to create an http session if does not exist yet. You can prevent this by adding the directive `<%@ page session="false" %>` to your JSP.